# Using Replicate AI, how can I pull files from cloud storage during build?

Tags: docker, machine-learning, replicate

I am building a docker image using `cog` from Replicate AI. The docker image will contain a pytorch model checkpoint for image classification. I would like to pull the checkpoint file from Google Cloud Storage at build time. If I were using docker directly then I would add something like this to my Dockerfile:

```
RUN gcloud storage cp gs://bucket/pytorch_model.bin model.bin
```

However, cog has its own way of building docker images using a `cog.yaml` file, and so far as I know, there is no Dockerfile that I can directly edit. Using cog, how can I pull a file from cloud storage into the container image at build time?